# ASP.NET MVC 5 CSS usage (td borders)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html-table, border

I have an issue with applying CSS styles to . I have the following code in my view:

```
@while (i < Model.Cells.Count)
        {
        <tr>
            @while (i < Model.Cells.Count && Model.Cells[i].X == k)
            {
                <td bgcolor=@Model.Cells[i].Col class=@Model.Cells[i].Borders>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>Model.Cells[i].Borders)</td>
                i++;
            }
        </tr>
        k++;
        }
```

It works kinda fine, but this line:

```
   <td bgcolor=@Model.Cells[i].Col 
   class=@Model.Cells[i].Borders>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>Model.Cells[i].Borders)</td>
```

seems to have a problem. In

```
@Model.Cells[i].Borders
```

It contains a string which looks like: "T"; "T L B R";   "B";   L R"; etc.
I also have css file, with classes:

```
.T {
border-top: 1px black;    
border-top-style: solid;
}
```

for every letter (T - top, B - bottom, R- right, L - left). So I assume to assign several classes to  element with one string. But when I compile my code, some of the borders are missing, and some is not doubled (if I have two cells with Right and Left borders near each other). I can not see any pattern in missing borders. Do you have any idea on how to fix this issue? Consider these screenshot: [image]

As you can see, borders are supposed to exist on the side where cells of different colors touch. Some of it are working right, some are not.

Comment: For a start you should be quoting it = `class="@Model.Cells[i].Borders"`

Comment: thanks fellow, I did think about that but but since it worked without quotes, I didn't really consider it as an issue

Comment: Lokk at the html your generating! If its "T L B R" it generates `<td class="T"  L B R>` (not `class="T L B R"`)